# Samsung Galaxy S6 Emulator in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any possibilities to create Samsung Galaxy S6 Emulator with its actual behavior (not just skin and resolution) in Android studio?

Comment: Try Genymotion device present there.

Comment: @SuhasB is it possible to get the exact OS behavior using Genymotion? not just skin and resolution as I mentioned.

Comment: Yes it almost works like OS behavior.

Comment: I think there is an answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577939/samsung-system-image-for-android-emulator

Answer (score -13, accepted):

You only have to install the [skin for the Galaxy S6](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000217) to you AVD (Android Virtual Device). This is the most accurate way to emulate an S6 regarding the documentation that Samsung has.

Take a look at [Install Samsung Galaxy S6 skin in your Android Emulator](http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/install-samsung-galaxy-s6-skin-in-your-android-emulator/):

> For Samsung devices, Samsung provide emulator skins for its flagships
>   devices like Galaxy S6, Galaxy S5 or Galaxy Note 4. In this tutorial,
>   we’re going to install Samsung Galaxy S6 Emulator skin but process is
>   the same for all Emulator skins you want to install on Eclipse.

It talks about eclipse, but it's applicable for the Android Studio too.

You also have a Samsung Official video [here](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095) which explains the same as the tutorial.

You also have this [Samsung Testlab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action) where you can test your apps in different Samsung devices which could be more interesting for you than the skin.

Comment: At the end it says, "You must note that only the appearance of the Samsung Emulator differs from the Generic Android Emulator. Functionalities are the same." Does it mean that it wont behave like Galaxy S6?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but it's the most accurate way I found in the Samsung docs, or maybe you can try if Genymotion can emulate it, but I don't think so.

Comment: installing skin just gives the look and feel of that device, at the end you can create AVDs with different resolutions with the same skin

Comment: The problem is that Samsung actually has a different app environment and does things in a different way and sometimes that way generates bugs that doesn't exist in vanilla android, and you can't find them. Skin is worthless for that, when you're trying to get to the meat.

Comment: Maybe you can try downloading the Samsung SDK or as someone suggested above, use Samsung Testlab.  Also, I have noted that both Google and Amazon have device farms that will test your code on real devices.  That maybe the best bet.  Hope that helps.

Comment: The question was talking about behavior, not just "look and feel". This is not a valid answer in my point of view (or it must start referring to Samsung Testlab as the main topic).

Comment: "We’re sorry, the requested URL is no longer available :
/home.do"

Comment: I second @Luan , OP is clearly stating that he wants not only the skin, but also behavior.

Answer (score 9):

It's Almost Impossible but there is a second choice called [Remote Test Lab](https://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab) , which lets you access and control a wide range of real Samsung devices online and also **It's totally free !**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm confronted with the same issue, as I'm trying to understand how to work with the [Samsung Health Android SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/health/android). 
Unfortunately, I found the following note on the [SDK documentation](https://developer.samsung.com/health/android/data/guide/process) that seems to rule out the possibility to use an emulator (at least in this instance):

> **Note** Samsung Health Android SDK doesn’t support the Emulator test.
>   Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API level 23) device or above is required to
>   test your app.