# Android studio how to see more phone models in the simulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I've noticed that in the simulator of Android Studio there's not the Samsung S6, Edge, s7 ecc. This are the one I have:

[image]

Is there a way to have them? Because I would like to test my app on them.

Comment: You can add your own AVD in AVD Manager

Comment: Yes but does this mean that I have to look for the screensize, ram ecc on the internet and then create my own AVD with the features of the samsung S6 ecc?

Comment: Use a **similar** one or **create** a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer from a similar post: [Samsung Galaxy S6 Emulator in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268812/samsung-galaxy-s6-emulator-in-android-studio)

> You only have to install the [skin for the Galaxy S6](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000217) to you AVD
>   (Android Virtual Device). This is the most accurate way to emulate an
>   S6 regarding the documentation that Samsung has.
>
> Take a look at [Install Samsung Galaxy S6 skin in your Android
>   Emulator](http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/install-samsung-galaxy-s6-skin-in-your-android-emulator/):
>
> > For Samsung devices, Samsung provide emulator skins for its flagships
> >     devices like Galaxy S6, Galaxy S5 or Galaxy Note 4. In this tutorial,
> >     we’re going to install Samsung Galaxy S6 Emulator skin but process is
> >     the same for all Emulator skins you want to install on Eclipse.
>
> It talks about eclipse, but it's applicable for the Android Studio
>   too.
>
> You also have a Samsung Official video [here](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095) which explains the
>   same as the tutorial.
>
> You also have this [Samsung Testlab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action) where you can test your apps
>   in different Samsung devices which could be more interesting for you
>   than the skin.

Look also at: [Emulate Samsung Galaxy Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745491/emulate-samsung-galaxy-tab?rq=1), where you would find this answer:

> To get the official Samsung Galaxy Tab emulator do the following:
>
> Open the Android SDK and AVD Manager Click on Available packages
>   Expand the Third party Add-ons. There you will see Samsung Electronics
>   add-ons. Once the add-on is installed create a new emulator. Under
>   Target you will see the new Samsung Tab settings, select that. That's
>   it!

Another way to get custom emulators like Samsung S6, Xperia Z3 or Motorola G is to install `Genymotion`, where you have more emulators then only Nexuses. Notice that Genymotion depends on VirtualBox so it would also might work faster then classic AVDs.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Genymotion's tip was essential. Thanks