# Samsung system image for Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy, android-rom

Is there any way to get the Android emulator to run a **system image** other than vanilla Android? I'm developing an app that works fine on the emulator, a physical Huawei device and a physical Motorola device, but experiences some weird issues on a Samsung Galaxy S7.

Since I don't have physical access to a Galaxy S7, is there any way to run an emulator that actually runs the Samsung official ROM? Note that I'm not talking about [an emulator skin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270625/930640), I'm talking about the actual system image.

Comment: No. Samsung doesn't make a version of TouchWiz that can run on an emulator. I think you'd be better off asking here about those "weird issues."

Answer (score 31, accepted):

While there might not be any Samsung system images to download and install on the Android Studio emulator, there is another option.

Samsung has something called [Remote Test Lab](https://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/), which lets you access and control a real Samsung device online. You have to join the Samsung Developers programme, and then you can use these test devices. Samsung uses a credit-based system for this, and you get 20 free credits every day, which you can then use to run test devices. Running a Galaxy S7 for 30 minutes cost me 2 credits.

This actually works surprisingly well, and only slightly more lagging than the AVD. It is even possible to get Logcat output by connecting to the device with ADB (right click on the device window for options).

Comment: This works but it would be nice to have an image, the remote devices are unable to connect to my proxies in order to actually test the app.

Comment: For anyone using the remote test lab - do not put anything important like passwords or logins into the clipboard, since it will be available for anyone to see.