# How can we add Samsung galaxy skin into android emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android development, I want to know how can we add Samsung galaxy devices/skin into my emulator?
I can able to add skins of Samsung galaxy but can't see in AVD manager.
I need help to understand this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Samsung Galaxy S6 Emulator in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268812/samsung-galaxy-s6-emulator-in-android-studio)

Comment: @AdityaKurkure Yes, I followed the same but can't see galaxy devices in avd manager. Do I need to do something in order to get this in AVD.?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Steps to add new skin into your Android Emulator:

1. Need to download the skin of your desired device, Recommended URL https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/galaxy_note_series.html to download
2. Then unzip this downloaded file, Now copy and paste this to /Users/YourUserName/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-29/skins
3. Launch android studio and open AVD manager
4. Now we need to add a device definition for that recently added skin
5. In AVD manager click to this create virtual device option
6. Now you will see the an option for New Hardware Profile option at the bottom left of this popup.
7. Click to this New Hardware Profile, you will get a popup for Configure Hardware Profile. Add device and device type then scroll down and you will find an option for Default skin dropdown, Choose your newly added skin
8. Afterwards press this finish button at the right bottom and you are done with device definition configuration.
9. Now you can create your own virtual device with this newly added device definition.

Comment: You are showing how to add a Samsung  skin for an AVD. But what I am looking for is not just a skin change but also its complete hardware and software duplicate.

Comment: The above steps are only for adding a skin into Emulators.

Comment: @SyedArsalanKazmi, then what are you doing in this topic? Tuning Android emulator is not easy, especially with other firmware. You should search this kind of questions.

Comment: no such thing as a /Library/ on my PC

Comment: @MwBakker you need to right click when you are in your user folder and click on 'Show view options' then you can click on 'Show Library folder'